# Get the full route to current action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple API with basic routing. It was setup using the default Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET Core API template.

I have this controller and action:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DocumentController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("info/{Id}")]
    public async Task<Data> Get(string Id)
    {
        //Logic
    }
}
```

So to reach this method, I must call `GET /api/document/info/some-id-here`.

**Is it possible with .NET Core, inside that method, to retrieve as a string the complete route?**

So I could do for example:

```
var myRoute = retrieveRoute();

// myRoute = "/api/document/info/some-id-here"
```

Comment: try [HttpGet("info/{Id?}")]

Comment: I there! thanks for your comment but the question is about retrieving as a string, within the method, the route followed to reach the method. My routing is working well at the moment and I can't set the Id as optional.

Comment: Ok, Question was edited.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can get the complete requested url using the **Request**  option (HttpRequest) in .Net Core.

```
var route = Request.Path.Value;
```

Your final code.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DocumentController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("info/{Id}")]
    public async Task<Data> Get(string Id)
    {
        var route = Request.Path.Value;
    }
}
```

*Result route: "/api/document/info/some-id-here"* //for example

Comment: that is great, when your code is inside the action. What if you need a path to an action, say, in a view?

Comment: @serge ```new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext.Request.Path.Value```

Comment: @serge In a view you can use `Context.Request`

Answer (score 12):

You can also ask MVC to create a new route URL based on the current route values:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DocumentController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("info/{Id}")]
    public async Task<Data> Get(string Id)
    {
        //Logic

        var myRoute = Url.RouteUrl(RouteData.Values);
    }
}
```

`Url.RouteUrl` is a helper method that lets you build a route URL given any route values. `RouteData.Values` gives you the route values for the **current** request.

Comment: Thanks it works too! Do you know how I can filter the part after /api/ for example?

Comment: @BlackHoleGalaxy What do you mean by 'filter'?

Comment: In my example retrieving only the part after /api/ of my route: `/document/info/Id`

Comment: @BlackHoleGalaxy You could always do `myRoute.Replace("/api", string.Empty)` as a quick hack.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the original route template on an API controller that was specified with any HttpMethod attribute then this will do it:

```
var routeAttribute = Url.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.First(d => d is HttpMethodAttribute);
var routeTemplate = ((HttpMethodAttribute)routeAttribute).Template;
```

If the original route attribute was: `[HttpGet("Self/{id}")]`

The routeTemplate value would be: `"Self/{id}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
Url.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template

"v{version}/{cardId}/cardsTest" {$1}
```

Comment: In .Net 5+ why is this not the right answer? Url.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template

Comment: Please explain your code. Also, you should note that this does not what is asked for in the question.