# MVC ASP NET Core, Keeping Routing URL with ActionLinks

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, actionlink

I'm struggling to keep my routing links when using Html helper ActionLinks.

I've set my routes similar to this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "test1",
                  template: "test1/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
                  defaults: null,
                  constraints: null,
                  dataTokens: new { Id = 1 });

routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "test2",
                  template: "test2/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
                  defaults: null,
                  constraints: null,
                  dataTokens: new { Id = 2 });
});
```

So, I can navigate to /Test1/Home/Index and /Test2/Home/Index.

On each page there are links created by the html helper BUT regardless if on Test2 page the helper creates the link /Test1/Controller/Action. I assume it creates the link based on the first route that's mapped, in this case Test1.

How can I make links on the pages keep the test2 etc part of the link?

The helpers I'm using are

```
@Html.ActionLink("text", "action", "controller")
```

Cheers

Comment: Which helper are you using, and how?

Comment: standard Helpers.  ie.  @Html.ActionLink("text", "action", "controller")

Comment: Have you tried `RouteUrl('test2', ...)`?

Comment: It's the same view being displayed, I wouldn't be able to hard code the routename into the routeurl helper. Unless I've miss understood

Comment: Ah, I see. I suppose you could find out the current route name then, and reuse it. Similar to what is being discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41511568/728795

Comment: oooooh, I'll have a look and see. Thanks

Comment: Any luck using RouteUrl helper?

Comment: No. I've now changed my approach. So I wont be relying on routing. I don't like the idea of writing lots of code for something that should be simple.  I'm still interested in finding an answer but unless a vanilla solution is discovered I'll stick with my new approach. Cheers for the help

Comment: It would probably help other answerers if you update the post with RouteUrl approach and how it did not work