# how to get current route controller full url path in net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

how to get current route controller full url path in net core 3.1?

if I am in method test of mycontroller, it should be:

```
https://example.com/demo/x/api/my/test
```

how to get `https://example.com/demo/x/api/my` programmatically?

I try:

```
 String originalPath = new Uri(HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl()).AbsoluteUri;
```

it returns `http://example.com/my/test`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755827/getting-absolute-urls-using-asp-net-core

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511568/get-the-full-route-to-current-action (at least if you don't need the the server/domain name in the URL).