# How I can get route (Url) from method via reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How I can get route (Url) from method via reflection.
From controller and method, like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Route("api/events/[controller]")]
public class ApprovedWorksController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
    
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ApprovedWorkResponse>> GetAsync(ApprovedWorkFilter filter)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

To:

```
api/events/ApprovedWorks ...
```

Comment: You mean this url; `@Url.Action("GetAsync", "ApprovedWorks")` ?

Comment: You don't need to use reflection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511568/get-the-full-route-to-current-action

Comment: @Hainan.Z I need, because I want to get all routes in my project where 8 controllers :(

Answer (score 1):

I use this, for solve problem:

```
var routeAttribute = controller.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(RouteAttribute));
      if (routeAttribute != null)
            Console.WriteLine(((RouteAttribute) routeAttribute).Template.Replace("/[controller]", "")
                                 + "/" + controller.Name.Replace("Controller", "")
                                 + "/" + methodInfo.Name);
```

Comment: Feels like you're solving the wrong problem. In asp.net core you can use `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider` to get information about all routes. There's probably something similar for asp.net

Comment: This is exactly what I needed when doing this from an external assembly. Thanks.

You do need to take care that if a controller is e.g. /api/[controller]/[action] but a method is [RouteAttribute(/FOO)], the actual url will be just /FOO, and non-slashed route will append such that /api/controller/action/FOO

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to use Reflection. All info you need about the **HTTP Request** can be found in `Request` and here is screenshot for you to see it in action:

[image]